# Console error when drawing to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, dictionary, tile

I have a main javascript file which is trying to draw a tilemap to a canvas for a game, and i have an included file which actually draws the maps etc, but im getting this error in firebug:

> TypeError: Value could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.
>   [Break On This Error]

```
ctx.drawImage(mapTiles[map[x][y]],x*tilesize, y*tilesize);
```

the main js which calls my level.js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var canvas = document.getElementById("TBG");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var ui = new Gui();
var level = new Level();

//----------Login/Register Gui --------------
$('#TBG').hide();
$('#load-new').hide();
$('#reg').hide();
$('#login').hide();

//if login_but is clicked do ui.login function
$('#login_but').click(ui.login);
//if reg_but is clicked do ui.register function
$('#reg_but').click(ui.register);

$('#new_but').click(function(){
    game_settings("new");
});

$('#load_but').click(function(){
    game_settings("load");
});

//if login_sumbit button is clicked do ui.login_ajax function
$("#login_submit").click(ui.login_ajax);

$("#reg_submit").click(ui.register_ajax);

$("#welcome").on("click", "#logout_but", ui.logout);

//____________________________________________
//Initialisation of game

function game_settings(state){
    if(state == "load"){
        ui.load_game();
        //do ajax call to load user last save
        //level.level_init(0,1);

        draw();
    }
    else{
        //set beginning params


        //Change screens
        ui.new_game();
        alert("new game");
    }
}

function draw () {

    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    level.draw(context);

    setTimeout(draw, 30);


}
// End Loop 
      });
```

and the file where this line of code (level.js) looks like this:

```
function Level(){

var tilesize = 32;
var map = 0;
var mapTiles = [];

   // var saved_level = level;
    //var saved_location = location;


map = [
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
];

    for (x = 1; x <= 256; x++) {
        var imageObj = new Image(); // new instance for each image
        imageObj.src = "images/prototype/"+x+".jpg";
        mapTiles.push(imageObj);
    }


this.draw = function(ctx) {
 for (var x = 0; x <= 31; x++){
        for ( var y = 0; y <= 31; y++){
            ctx.drawImage(mapTiles[map[x][y]],x*tilesize, y*tilesize);

    }
}
};

}
```

Have any of you ever encountered this error?

and how would i correct the issue, thanks tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about canvas and everything else and look at the `map` array and the code that uses it. Let's rip out the canvas code and examine the array accesses with some `console.log()` calls:

```
map = [
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
];

console.log( map.length );
console.log( map[0].length );

for (var x = 0; x <= 31; x++){
    for ( var y = 0; y <= 31; y++){
        console.log( x, y, map[x], map[x] && map[x][y] );
    }
}
```

Do you see the problem? You may be able to spot it by thinking about what those `console.log()` calls will print. If not, paste that code into the Chrome developer console and see what it does. (BTW, where the last argument has `map[x] && map[x][y]`, that's essentially the same as `map[x][y]` but it protects the code from crashing when `map[x]` is `undefined` as you will see happen in the log.)

Now that we now that `map[x][y]` is `undefined` some of the time, go back to the `drawImage()` call, which uses this as the image argument:

```
mapTiles[ map[x][y] ]
```

When `map[x][y]` is `undefined`, what will that expression evaluate to?

Comment: Socrates, is that you? :p  Answer: we're trying to access map array elements that are beyond the number of elements we've actually set. (PS Hi Michael Geary, I'm old enough that I was taught using the Socratic Method in college!)

Comment: Plato! How good to see you, old friend. Yes, another way to put it is "What does `mapTiles[undefined]` evaluate to?" And how is our friend Aristotle? Have you heard from him lately? I've been wanting to ask him what it means to overflow a stack.